# What are klipos that rest on your body when you're asleep?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, netilat-yadayim-washing

BH

I heard that there are klipos that rest on your body when you're asleep, and when you wake up they jump to the nails on your hands, and that’s why you need to wash your hands in the mornings.

Are these the same klipos that get created if a person sins, Chas ve shalom. If not, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

I heard in a shiur a while ago that what we are discussing is **insensitivity to others**. Just like the nails are parts of our body that have no feeling and are "dead", so to we can be like this towards others: unempathetic, insensitive to their feelings and needs, and unbothered if we upset or hurt them, *ch'v*.

We wash this "klipa" away in the morning with *netila*.

If I find the shiur, or the original source, I will update this question.